# How do I access a property on a base class that is for a web component?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component, native-web-component

I would like to set the html namespace for the component on the Base class, but it seems you can't do `NavBar.ns` without creating an instance, which makes the web component not render.

```
import Base from './Base.js';

class NavBar extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('ns', this.ns);
    this.innerHTML = '...';
  }
}

console.log('ns2', NavBar.ns);  // undefined here
customElements.define(`${NavBar.ns}-navbar`, NavBar);
```

Base.js:

```
class Base extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.ns = 'wce';
  }


}

export default Base;
```

Comment: So, you might want to make it a static field (since you aren't creating an instance), or you'll need to use the `new` operator. So in `Base` add a method: `static get ns() { return 'wce'; }`, then try again.

Comment: so that worked but the if i want to access it internally `this.ns` is undefined...is there way to make that work too?

Comment: You'll have to do it manually/twice, one static and another for each instance, so in the constructor just do what you're doing and keep the static field as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `Navbar.ns` because you aren't creating an *instance* (object) of Navbar, and `this.ns` will be applied for each `new` call to navbar, e.g. `const navbar = new Navbar(); navbar.ns; // <-- wce`. You aren't creating an *instance* of `Navbar`, so you can create a *static* field, which allows you to access a field without creating a class instance.

In `base.js`:

```js
class Base extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  static get ns() {
    return 'wce';
  }
}

export default Base;
```

*`static`* allows us to access class fields without, and only without creating a `new` instance.
Now, when you call `NavBar.ns` it will return `"wce"` using a *getter*.

However, you also wanted to be able to access `.ns` when you (`customElements.define`) create a new instance. You'll have to set an addition `this` call:

```js
class Base extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.ns = 'hello';
  }
  static get ns() {
    return 'world';
  }
}

export default Base;
```

In your case you can change both "hello" and "world" to "wce" if you want them to "work the same way."

Now, let's say you want to access `ns`, if you aren't creating an instance you would do:

```js
NavBar.ns; // <-- "world"
```

But if you were creating an instance (like in `customElements.define`), you use the `new` operator to access `this.ns`:

```js
const navbar = new NavBar();
navbar.ns; // "hello"
```

(I used "hello" and "world" instead of "wce" just for the illustration.)
Now with the added code you could use it as in your example:

```js
                       /*  "wce-navbar"  */
customElements.define(`${NavBar.ns}-navbar`, NavBar);
```

[Some docs about `static`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)